# Rails 3.2 strange behavior of include? with AR collections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**UPDATE** This was weird problem, can not reproduce it now. I did `drop_database DBNAME`, created new one, populated it from backup and now it behaves OK - select selects proper record, however I have changed code to more using AR query interface, as in selected answer.

I have e-commerce application and noticed strange behavior. A real data example:

```
1.9.3p484 :096 > cart.cart_entries.collect{|e| e.part.product_categories.collect{|pc| pc.id}}
 => [[7], [7], [7], [5, 22], [22], [8], [22], [22]]
```

So, these cart entries belongs to some parts, which have product categories, right?

```
1.9.3p484 :112 > c.class.to_s
 => "Coupon" 
1.9.3p484 :097 > c.product_category.id
 => 22
```

We have also Coupon class, which also belongs to product category, now strange thing:

```
1.9.3p484 :098 > cart.cart_entries.select{|e| e.part.product_categories.include?(c.product_category)}
 => []
```

Am I doing something wrong? I would expect some of cart entries will be selected, since both part and coupon have common ProductCategory.

After some testing I have narrowed problem to this:

```
1.9.3p484 :105 > cat1=cart.cart_entries.last.part.product_categories.first; [cat1.id, cat1.class.to_s]
 => [22, "ProductCategory"] 
1.9.3p484 :110 > cat = ProductCategory.find(22); cat.eql? cat1
 => false
```

So, I have some object with the same class and same id they should be identical, right?

```
1.9.3p484 :113 > cat1.instance_of?(ProductCategory)
 => false
```

Well, is it some kind of bug in ruby 1.9.3???

Comment: @ArupRakshit - no does not help. Problem is narrowed down in last lines - both cat and cat1 are ProductCategory object and have id 22. From some reason Object#instance_of? for object cat1 tells it is not ProductCategory!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can better do this by using ActiveRecord Query

```
# cart.cart_entries.select{|e| e.part.product_categories.include?(c.product_category)}

CartEntry.joins(:parts => :product_categories).where("product_categories.id = ?", product_category.id)
```

This would fetch you cart entries of a particular ProductCategory and would reduce DB querying to some extent.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Probably this will be way to go :) As an explanation - this application has it roots in 2007 and then was based on Rails 1.2 thus AR query interface is not used in all places as it should be now ;)

Answer (score 1):

`1.9.3p484 :098 > cart.cart_entries.select{|e| e.part.product_categories.include?(c.product_category)}`

I think its better to compare IDs instead of whole objects, because if they come from different parent object, it may return false.
Also, it should raise your performance, so try with this:

`cart.cart_entries.select{|e| e.part.product_categories.pluck(:id).include?(c.product_category.id)}`

Comment: But that what's include? does - checks if both objects are the same class and have equal ID. For some reason checking class was failing. I have changed code to do more on SQL side